# How to sort column header values of crosstab in jasper?

Tags: sorting, jasper-reports, crosstab

My column values in jasper crosstab has month names.

Problem is they are sending from backend in various objects, so I can't sort month name coming from backend.
<

Because of that this issue has occurred. 
[image]

I want to sort these columns in Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May Aug order.

Can I do that setting a if else if else condition in column value in jasper?

Comment: Yes, you can apply any sorting rule

Comment: @AlexK I'm trying to add multiple if else conditions in jasper but seems impossible

Comment: It is possible - you can use ternary operator

Comment: @AlexK can you please give me an example?

Comment: Also  
@AlexK  if condition is true what should I return as a value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sort your crosstab header you have two options:

1. Create a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) class in java and pass that to the columnGroup's bucket expression in `comparatorExpression`
2. Create a measure that is sortable and pass that to `orderByExpression`.

In this example I will use method 2 and presume that the backend returns the month in date format `MMM`, hence I create a date object and get the time from this. If the month name is not in `MMM` format you would need to implement a ternary expression as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/users/876298/alex-k) by [Alex K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/876298/alex-k).

```
new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd").parse("2000-" + $F{Month} + "-01").getTime()
```

Create the measure:

```
<measure name="monthSort" class="java.lang.Long">
    <measureExpression><![CDATA[new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd").parse("2000-" + $F{Month} + "-01").getTime()]]></measureExpression>
</measure>
```

Add the measure to the `orderByExpression` in the `columnGroup` (avoiding null pointer if variabile is not instanced yet)

```
<columnGroup name="Month" height="20" totalPosition="End">
    <bucket class="java.lang.String">
        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{Month}]]></bucketExpression>
        <orderByExpression><![CDATA[($V{monthSort}==null?0:$V{monthSort})]]></orderByExpression>
    </bucket>
    ....
 </columnGroup>
```

## Full example

**Data**

```
+------+-------+-------+
| Name | Month | Value |
+------+-------+-------+
| cat1 | Jan   |   121 |
| cat1 | Feb   |    52 |
| cat1 | Aug   |    73 |
| cat1 | Mar   |    14 |
| cat2 | Feb   |    54 |
| cat2 | Apr   |    80 |
| cat2 | Dec   |    10 |
| cat2 | Jan   |    20 |
+------+-------+-------+
```

**jrxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="SortValue" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="0ba3ded0-a5d4-435b-a2b1-c61ecd71ac00">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="Months"/>
    <style name="Crosstab_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Crosstab_CG" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Crosstab_CT" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#005FB3">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Crosstab_CD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <queryString language="csv">
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="Name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Month" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Value" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <summary>
        <band height="300" splitType="Stretch">
            <crosstab>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="520" height="70" uuid="13bf3aea-b677-4389-bbd5-60cb98bad0c6">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
                </reportElement>
                <rowGroup name="Name" width="60" totalPosition="End">
                    <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{Name}]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabRowHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CH">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="f9becd93-ee0a-443b-bf24-d3c5f903d2b7"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{Name}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabRowHeader>
                    <crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="87613864-7410-44f6-a39f-7a727545db9d"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Total Name]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                </rowGroup>
                <columnGroup name="Month" height="20" totalPosition="End">
                    <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{Month}]]></bucketExpression>
                        <orderByExpression><![CDATA[($V{monthSort}==null?0:$V{monthSort})]]></orderByExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabColumnHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CH">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="f8957674-bebb-4c29-9799-ff0b1756d910"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{Month}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabColumnHeader>
                    <crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="50a78979-ea87-457d-aced-36a474659b62"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Total Month]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                </columnGroup>
                <measure name="Value_MEASURE" class="java.lang.String" calculation="First">
                    <measureExpression><![CDATA[$F{Value}]]></measureExpression>
                </measure>
                <measure name="monthSort" class="java.lang.Long">
                    <measureExpression><![CDATA[new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd").parse("2000-" + $F{Month} + "-01").getTime()]]></measureExpression>
                </measure>
                <crosstabCell width="60" height="20">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CD">
                        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="f53a65f4-1f08-4856-92a4-09267c6c073c"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{Value_MEASURE}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" columnTotalGroup="Month">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="0a17d733-1388-4df9-b754-182eaa09eca8"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{Value_MEASURE}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="Name">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="2bcf8a9c-8315-4508-9397-4850b08957f9"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{Value_MEASURE}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="Name" columnTotalGroup="Month">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="5431126e-8ed1-4c20-be7b-f88df55039c2"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{Value_MEASURE}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
            </crosstab>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

**Output**

[image: result]

Comment: OMG such a detailed answer. Thank you.

Comment: @pippi Yw just trying to make something useful also for future users